# Matrix operation in R: I have a square matrix whose determinant is zero, i need to find its inverse in R programing. Is it possible ,if yes how?

Tags: r, matrix

I  have a square matrix whose determinant is zero, I need to find the inverse of that matrix in R programing. Is it possible ,if yes how?
when I'm using the solve() function an error is coming since the determinant is 0.

Comment: Matrix inverse cannot exist when determinate is zero, which is provable

Comment: Suppose det(A) = 0 and it’s inverse exists. Then det(A^(-1)A) = det(I) = 1 and det(A^(-1)A) = det(A^(-1))det(A) = 0. Contradiction, therefore the inverse does not exist.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem as posed is not solvable by definition

Answer (score 4):

A matrix with determinant 0 does not have an inverse but one can calculate a [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) (also see [Moore Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)) which is not a true inverse but may be useful depending on what you want to do.  See the `ginv` function in the MASS package (which comes with R).

```
M <- matrix(1:9, 3)

det(M)
## [1] 0

solve(M)  # can't invert 
## Error in solve.default(M) : 
##   Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0

library(MASS)
ginv(M)
##            [,1]          [,2]       [,3]
## [1,] -0.6388889 -5.555556e-02  0.5277778
## [2,] -0.1666667 -5.551115e-17  0.1666667
## [3,]  0.3055556  5.555556e-02 -0.1944444
```

Although `M %*% ginv(M)` is not the identity matrix `ginv(M)` is such that `M %*% ginv(M) %*% M` equals `M` .

```
all.equal(M %*% ginv(M) %*% M, M)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Since inversion of a matrix includes division of each cell by  its determinant, it is not possible to invert a matrix whose determinant is zero.